# Putting two child layout inside a parent layout with equal weight distribution in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use two child layout (one linear layout and one relative layout) inside a parent layout (relative layout) in such a way that both of the child layout will take exactly half of the screen and items inside of each child layout will not cause one child layout to get more width than another one! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your illustration, the red box is a RelativeLayout, whereas the green boxes are a LinearLayout and a RelativeLayout.

A simple solution would be to center an empty View inside the RelativeLayout and align the two child Views against it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/v_center" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/v_center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

A nice little bonus here is that you can provide some spacing between the two by specifying the View's dimensions.

Beware, however, that RelativeLayouts aren't very efficient, and nesting them is an especially bad idea. I suggest using the hierarchy viewer tool to inspect the layout timings to make sure it's relatively fast, and to try to avoid nesting the layouts in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy, use parameter layout_weight in children of LinearLayout, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```